# У меня есть два питон файла. Они импортируют друг друга, и в результате возникает ошибка

Tags: python

Один файл, это селениум парсер, который собирает данные, и  передает их программе которая записывает их в базу данных. Второй файл отвечает за взаимодействие с базой данных и для её обновления, вызывает парсер - это вызывает ошибку.
Файлы обьеденены через import

```
Файл tl_selenium
import tl_database 
Файл tl_database
import tl_selenium
```

Как это можно исправить или как изменить структуру файгов?

Answer (score 0):

По нормальному нужно делать всё это в файле `main.py`, который будет подключать обе ваши библиотеки и вызывать какие-то действия из них в нужном порядке. Подключаемые файлы не должны сами инициировать никаких действий, они должны только выполнять какие-то действия, которые от них требуются по запросу - например, парсить и возвращать результат, или записывать данные в базу. Управление потоком этих действий должно идти из `main`.

Такая схема удобна и для тестирования библиотек (они "вещь в себе" и ни от чего не зависят, можно просто вызвать, получить результат и проверить его).

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ очевидный, но от этого, не менее разумный. Переделаю логику программы.